# ASCII to DEC in PHP

Tags: php

convert DEC to ASCII:

$ascii=chr($t);

I need a code that converts ASCII to DEC.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

Answer (score 1):

not sure what kind of input/ouput you should have, but probably something like this:

```
function ascii_to_dec($str)
{
  for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($str); $i < $j; $i++) {
    $dec_array[] = ord($str{$i});
  }
  return $dec_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ord` function](http://docs.php.net/ord) converts a single byte to its integer value (0  ≥ *i* ≥ 255) and not just the 128 characters of the ASCII character set.